# Visual Studio C# can not see Dll in GAC

Tags: c#, assembly, reference, gac

I installed my dll to Global Assembly Cache Folder like in this image
[image]
But visual studio c# can not see this dll when i want to add a reference to this dll or browse this dll in toolbox.

Can you please tell me what i was wrong with the installation to GAC?

I use visual studio c# 2022

Thank you,

Comment: What type of project are you targeting? If it’s .net core then theres no gac

Comment: @DanielA.White my project is .net framework 4.8.1

Answer (score -1):

- Verify that the DLL is actually in the GAC. You can do this by
  opening the Developer Command Prompt for Visual Studio and typing
  "gacutil /l" to list the contents of the GAC. If you don't see the
  DLL in the list, it may not be installed in the GAC correctly.
- Check that you are referencing the correct version of the DLL. If you
  have multiple versions of the same DLL installed in the GAC, you need
  to make sure you are referencing the correct one. You can view the
  version information of a DLL in the GAC by using the "gacutil /l"
  command.
- Make sure that you are using the correct assembly name when
  referencing the DLL. The assembly name is not necessarily the same as
  the DLL file name. You can view the assembly name of a DLL in the GAC
  by using the "gacutil /l" command.
- Try adding the DLL reference manually by browsing to the DLL file in
  the GAC. To do this, right-click on the "References" folder in your
  project in Visual Studio and select "Add Reference...". Then, click
  the "Browse" button and navigate to the location of the DLL in the
  GAC (usually located in C:\Windows\assembly).
- Check the permissions of the DLL in the GAC. Make sure that the
  account running Visual Studio has permission to access the DLL in the
  GAC. If you are running Visual Studio as an administrator, this
  should not be an issue.
- If none of the above solutions work, you may need to try uninstalling
  and reinstalling the DLL in the GAC, or try using a different version
  of the DLL.

Comment: I can see my dll with gacutil /l command and the dll has correct name and version.